# buttons and a refreshing display area in wxpython

Tags: python, layout, wxpython

I am a humanities teacher, trying to adapt a simple app to help teachers manage classroom interaction - it takes attendance, then allows for calling on random attending students in class, or breaking them into groups, or recording an excused absence, and so on. I've long had a working version in PHP / MySQL running locally on my laptop, but I want to make it a portable python / sqlite app, with an eye toward releasing into the wild for other teachers to use and improve.

But I'm totally new to wxPython, and not really strong on object-oriented programming generally. I have spent hours reading (or skimming through) a fair number of tutorials and introductions and StackOverflow questions, and I've played with wxFormBuilder, but I do not feel like I'm making progress - I'm still quite confused about panels and sizers and layouts, and which bits should belong to what parents.

I think if I could just get this minimal version working, that would go a long way toward my real app. The toolbar-like buttons along the top seem to work fine, but I'd like a "display" area below with a minimal (but expandable) vertical size, a centered text area, and a row of 2-3 buttons in the display area below that text. This display area should change and clear depending on the button pushed above. Here's what I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(-1,-1))

        # self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(-1,300))

        # buttons bar

        self.top_button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.btn_left = wx.Button(self, -1, label="left")
        self.btn_right = wx.Button(self, -1, label="right")

        self.btn_left.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnLeft)
        self.btn_right.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRight)

        self.top_button_sizer.Add(self.btn_left, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.top_button_sizer.Add(self.btn_right, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.display_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.text_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.display_text = wx.StaticText(self, label="Push a button!")
        self.display_buttons_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.text_sizer.Add(self.display_text, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
        self.display_sizer.Add(self.text_sizer, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
        self.display_sizer.Add(self.display_buttons_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer.Add(self.top_button_sizer, 0, wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND)
        # self.sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.sizer.Add(self.display_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnLeft(self,e):
        # for child in self.display_buttons_sizer.GetChildren():
        #     child.Destroy()
        # ^ my attempt to "clear" causes a SegFault
        for child in self.display_buttons_sizer.GetChildren():
            child.Destroy()
        self.display_text.SetLabel("Hey lefty!")
        self.btn_hey = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Hey yourself lefty.")
        self.btn_whoa = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Whoa there lefty.")
        self.display_buttons_sizer.Add(self.btn_hey, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.display_buttons_sizer.Add(self.btn_whoa, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer.Layout()

    def OnRight(self,e):
        # for child in self.display_buttons_sizer.GetChildren():
        #     child.Destroy()
        # ^ my attempt to "clear" causes a SegFault!
        self.display_text.SetLabel("Hey righty!")
        self.btn_hey = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Hey yourself righty.")
        self.btn_whoa = wx.Button(self, -1, label="Whoa there righty.")
        self.display_buttons_sizer.Add(self.btn_hey, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.display_buttons_sizer.Add(self.btn_whoa, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer.Layout()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "MWE")
app.MainLoop()
```

(I'm sure this is abhorrent code in lots of ways.) Should I put in a panel somewhere? Where, and how? Would it be easier to learn about "notebooks" instead of using my top buttons? How do I properly clear what's in the "display" area below for the next button push?

**Bonus points:** the most complicated of the top buttons on my real app is for taking attendance. It would display many lines of text (the students in that class, which I get from sqlite; I've worked that part out I think) with radio buttons for present / absent next to each line, and then record in the database. Hints about this would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this sort of thing several different ways. You can swap out panels when a button is pushed or you could just use a `wx.Notebook` which is basically the same idea. I wrote up a tutorial on panel switching here that you might find helpful:

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

It uses a menu instead of buttons, but that wouldn't be hard to change. Here's a simple example that doesn't do panel switching, but does show how to add a multiline text control that clears itself when a button is pressed:

```
import wx

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btn_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        left_button = wx.Button(self, label='Left')
        left_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_left)
        btn_sizer.Add(left_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        right_button = wx.Button(self, label='Right')
        right_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_right)
        btn_sizer.Add(right_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.main_sizer.Add(btn_sizer, 0, wx.CENTER)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)

    def on_left(self, event):
        self.text_ctrl.Clear()
        self.text_ctrl.SetValue('Left')

    def on_right(self, event):
        self.text_ctrl.Clear()
        self.text_ctrl.SetValue('Right')



class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(-1,-1))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "MWE")
app.MainLoop()
```

This also demonstrates how to add a panel, which is recommended as panels give you the right "look" on all platforms and it also enables tabbing between controls.

You could easily add another set of buttons to the bottom by using the same concepts shown here and then just adding the second set of button's sizer to the main sizer.

If you want to do lines of text with some kind of radio or check button, I would recommend using a `wx.ListCtrl` or (better), `ObjectListView` (https://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#recipe-checkbox) (see also https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/)

You can tie an event to the checkbox that can then update your database appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this long question! I've been since playing with PyQt5 (and watching a Udemy course) in part because the signal/slot seems easier to me than button binding, and I'm planning to open-source anyway. But seeing how these things are done in both wxPython and PyQt helps me triangulate, and I may switch back. I hope this question / answer is helpful to others too!

Comment: wxPython has pubsub built-in, which does a lot of what PyQt's signal/slot stuff does, although to be fair, PyQt's signal/slot stuff is more powerful.

Comment: Also note that there is now Qt for Python / PySide2, which might be a better fit for you than PyQt if you really want to got the Qt route